# Select List<T> item with max value using LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have List loadRecords where T type defines as follow

```
public class TransformerLoadRecord
{

    public double TotalLoadKva { get; set; }
    public double TotalLoadKwh { get; set; }
    public string LoadDate { get; set; }
    public string LoadTime { get; set; }
    public long Fid { get; set;}
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "User Id:" + UserId +
               " Session Id:" + SessionId +
               " Fid:" + Fid.ToString() +
               " Load Date:" + LoadDate + 
               " Load Time:" + LoadTime + 
               " Total Load KWH:" + TotalLoadKwh.ToString() + 
               " Total Load KVA:" + TotalLoadKva.ToString();
    }
}
```

I need to get the item with max TotalLoadKva from the List of items (about 1900)
This is work

```
var mxKVALoad = loadRecords.Max(l => l.TotalLoadKva);
```

But I need all other properties and this code does not work and return more than one item

```
var maxLoadRecord = from txLoadValues in loadRecords 
                    group txLoadValues by txLoadValues.TotalLoadKva 
                         into txLoadValueGroup 
                     select txLoadValueGroup.OrderByDescending(l => l.TotalLoadKva).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I am doing wrong here? Can you explain please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to sort (descending) the source list and take the first element:

```
var elementWithMaxKVA = loadRecords.OrderByDescending(l => l.TotalLoadKva).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this is not the fastest way, because `OrderBy*` will have to do more work than simply look up the max value.

You could instead implement your own extension method like that:

```
// error handling and argument checks ommitted for brevity
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TComp>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TComp> selector) where TComp : IComparable
{    
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        TSource max = default(TSource);
        TComp maxV = default(TComp);
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) return max; // or throw

        max = enumerator.Current;
        maxV = selector(max);

        while(enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource current = enumerator.Current;
            TComp currentV = selector(current);
            if (currentV.CompareTo(maxV) <= 0) continue;
            maxV = currentV;
            max = current;
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
var elementWithMaxKVA = loadRecords.MaxBy(l => l.TotalLoadKva);
```

---

I think the [MoreLinq nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) already contains such a `MaxBy` method.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Comment: @SergheiT You're welcome. If this is your preferred answer and solved your question, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so you need to group them just for getting record with highest `TotalLoadKva`,you can just use `OrderByDescending` to sort them on the `TotalLoadKva` and then select the top first record using `First` or `FirstOrDefault` method:

```
var maxKVALoad = loadRecords.OrderByDescending(l => l.TotalLoadKva).FirstOrDefault();
                 // will return the record with highest value of TotalLoadKva
```

the preferred way will be to use `FirstOrDefault()` as `First()` will throw exception saying:

> The Sequence contains no elements

If it is guarranted that there will always be rows returned then `First()` can be safe to use, otherwise use `FirstOrDefault` which will not throw exception if collection is empty.

Comment: This will end in an exception if loadRecords has no entries; FirstOrDefault() will be better.

Comment: added that to answer as well @MightyBadaboom

Comment: Why even suggest `First` if the preferred way is `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: @Default there can be use-case where we know in advance that there will always be data available

Comment: There are use cases where `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` is also the better option but you're not explaining them. My comment here was referring to the following statement: "You can use `First`. However the preferred way is `FirstOrDefault` so use that instead". To me it'd be more fluent if it said "You can use `FirstOrDefault`. If you require an element to exist you can use `First`." i.e. the answer reads as "you can use this, or if you require this use this" instead of "you can use this, but don't do it, use this instead".

Comment: `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` are not relevant any way to this particular question

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
var mxKVALoad = loadRecords
                .Where(l => l.totalLoadKva == loadRecords.Max(l => l.TotalLoadKva));
```

Alternatively, you can use `MaxBy` from the [`MoreLINQ` library](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs)